# Could not have helped but + do/did/done?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentence:

The simp could not have helped but come/came running the second the girl called him.

Should I use 'come' or 'came' for this sentence? And if I should use 'come', would it be the infinitive or the past participle?

Also, could 'had come' work?

Because 'not..X.. but..Y..' feels like a pretty common structure that negates X and affirms Y. So I feel like X and Y should be of equal status. And in this case, 'could not have helped but ___', X being have helped and Y being some form of 'come' so wait, should it be 'have come' instead?

Comment: Do you mean 'There was nothing he could do to help, but he came anyway', or 'he couldn't help coming'?

Comment: I mean the simp being a simp could not have let go of the chance of simping by showing up for the girl.

Comment: [No: the answer is here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cannot+help+but%2C+cannot+have+helped+but%2Ccould+not+have+helped+but%2Ccould+not+help+but&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20help%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20have%20helped%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20have%20helped%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20help%20but%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20help%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20have%20helped%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20have%20helped%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20help%20but%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I had to look up the meaning of _simp_, a completely new word to me, but I think the construction you want is _could not help but come running_.

Comment: The Perfect format *(He **couldn't have helped** but laugh)* is "valid", but vanishingly rare compare to Simple Past *(He **couldn't help** but laugh)*. But that doesn't mean you *can't* use it. It's a stylistic choice (just not a ***common*** choice! :)

Comment: @KateBunting It's not in the OED. Is this some rude teen slang expression? If so, then I wonder why it was needed to make a point of grammar that seem to call for a simpler word here.

Answer (score 3):

*Can't help but*  is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cannot+help+but). It's followed by the bare infinitive of a verb.
<sub>Source: The Free Dictionary</sub>

If you need a past sense, use *couldn't help but*.

> *The simp can't help but come running the second the girl calls him.*
>
> *The simp couldn't help but come running the second the girl called him.*

I can't think of a need for a perfect version, but [a few have used it](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=96227772).
<sub>Source: Corpus of Contemporary American English</sub>

.

Further reading: Grammarphobia—[We can’t help but change](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/08/cant-help-but.html)